# I want to remove all english characters and digits from arabic text

Tags: php, regex

I have this text

```
اريد ان احذف هذا النص english text من الجمله 123
```

after apply this RE (PHP code):

```
$tag = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", '',$tag);
```

the expected result is: اريد ان احذف هذا النص من الجمله

but I got اريد ان احذف هذا النص english text من الجمله 123

what is the wrong in RE?

Comment: your expression has a start and end tag ... in words it searching at the beginning for english text 123 which ends with english text (: ... fix the regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$tag = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", '',$tag);` change this

to

```
$tag = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", '',$tag);
```

remove ^$ end tag from regex
and try

Comment: Thanks works, but if I want to remove any special char such "/@#$%&*" as well, what should i do?

Comment: include them inside [] for example [a-zA-Z0-9@$%#..] willl work

Comment: Just don't forget to escape those special characters, used as tokens in the RegEx ;-)

Comment: meant: i do not want to add them manually if any way to catch them using RE

Comment: Or just use an "inverted" pattern. That is, remove all characters except arabic ones ;)

Comment: yeah @Havelock you can do that way just to match arabic characters and ignore all

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of the tokens to match beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string, hence there's not match and further no replacement is made. You should remove them and the modified RegEx
`/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`
will work then.
**Update**
Following the request in your comments to the accepted answer, here's [an improved RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/eG9oZ0/1) to suit your needs.

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes... take my upvote, as your answer is the only one to actually explain OPs mistake instead of just saying "try this" without any explanation.

Comment: remove * and replace it with + because * will damage charset

Comment: @AymanHussein A quantifier can't "damage charset", but see my update answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
    $testString = "اريد ان احذف هذا النص english text من الجمله 123";

 echo $newString = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", '',$testString);
```